# How to Use NodeJs without Mongoose

Tags: mongodb

I am getting really good at NodeJs and AngularJs. After building a sizable application, I have come to the conclusion that Mongoose is not for me. I want to use pure MongoDb.

I have done a pretty good job refactoring my server code. I pulled all my functions out of my routes and into controllers. Currently however, my controllers are using Mongoose and they are connected to Mongo via the schema.

Current code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    errMsg = require('../../../utilities/errorMsg'),
    MyMongooseSchema = require('./models/myMongooseModel');

module.exports = {
    all: function (req, res) {
        MyMongooseSchema.find({}).exec(function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
               ....
            });
        }
        res.send(results);
    })
}
```

Again I do not want this. I want the dynamism of MongoDb. I tried this to no avail.

**db.js:**

```
function MongoDbConnect(dbName){
    var db = 'mongodb://localhost/' + dbName;
    MongoClient.connect(db, function (err, db) {
       if(err){
           console.log('Error connecting to database')
       } else {
     return db;        }
 });}
 exports.MongoDbConnect = MongoDbConnect;
```

**controller: [that is called from respective router]**

```
var database = require('../../../config/db');

module.exports =  {
  all: function (req, res) {
    var db = database.MongoDbConnect('myDbName');
    db.collection('MyCollectionName').find({}, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errMsg.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        res.send(results);
    })
}}
```

Obviously, this is not working.

What would be the appropriate way to create a well refactored database connection that any controller can call on, with whatever database the controller needs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hey everybody, thanks sooooo much for your help !***

```
    var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
    var db = mongoskin.db('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase?auto_reconnect', {safe:true});
    db.collection('Menu').find({}).toArray(function(error, menu){
        if (error) return next(error);
        res.send(menu || [])
    })
```